# trying to use an existing value in a href on a xsl page

Tags: xslt, href, tel

Im trying to create a page that replaces where the 0000000000 with the value of phnumber that is on the line below. this is a xsl page that is displaying the details of users on a database

The code below gets the data to be displayed from my database

```
<xsl:template match="phone" >
<p>
<xsl:value-of select="phnumber"/> : <xsl:value-of select="phtype" />
</p>

<a href="tel:000000000" target="_top">Phone</a>
<br></br>
    <a href="sms:000000000" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract the '00000000' part from the href attribute: you can separate a string into substrings, basically you want the content after the : character.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@href, ':')">
```

This assumes the : is only used to separate the number type from the number itself (so there are no numbers in the form '0000:0000').

Comment: no i was trying to make the 00000000 equal the value of "phnumber" on the line above

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:{phnumber}" target="_top">Phone</a><xsl:value-of select="phnumber"/>
```

Comment: Please, add more context to your answer. What was wrong or missing here?